# Align pictures horizontally using div tags so they spread out

Tags: html, css

I can't get it to align horizontally, I've tried using some tags and stuff but it wont work.

**HTML / CSS**

```css
#nav {
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: justify;
  -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
  text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <a href="istHome.html">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50" height="50">
  </a>
  <a href="Operations.html">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50" height="50">
  </a>
  <a href="System.html">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50" height="50">
  </a>
  <a href="EndUser.html">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50" height="50">
  </a>
  <a href="AboutMe.html">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50" height="50">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make `text-align:center` in you css.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pseudo element `::after` like this:

```css
#nav {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
}

#nav::after
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    content: '';
    font-size: 0;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
<a href="istHome.html"><img src="Home.PNG" height="50"></a>
<a href="Operations.html"><img src="Operations and Maintenence.PNG" height="50"></a>
<a href="System.html"><img src="Systems Development.PNG" height="50"></a>
<a href="EndUser.html"><img src="EndUserSupport.PNG" height="50"></a>
<a href="AboutMe.html"><img src="About Me.PNG" height="50"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below css will do it for you

```
#nav {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
  text-justify: distribute-all-lines;    
}
```